# как прокрутить элемент в видимую область через scrollIntoView, но чтобы не скроллилась сама страница?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: coral;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1>The Element Object</h1>
<h2>The scrollIntoView() Method</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll</button>

<p>Click "Scroll" to scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>


<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("content");
  element.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Может показаться, что она и так не скроллиться, но если блок увеличить, то страница тоже будет скроллиться

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: coral;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1>The Element Object</h1>
<h2>The scrollIntoView() Method</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction(500)">Scroll</button>

<p>Click "Scroll" to scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>


<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  <p>Some text inside an element.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(number) {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.scrollTop = number
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Тут просто выбирается на каком уровне скролла будет элемент, прямо в функции можете выбирать уровень (Писать только числа). Пример: `myFunction(123)`.

К слову тут я выбрал другой элемент который пользователь как раз и скроллит.